# Why does artifactory7 Plattform ä generate many api keys on its own? What are they used for?

Tags: api, key, artifactory, access-token

I am not an artifactory expert, but I have noticed artifactory 7 for 5 months and yesterday that there are a few access tokens with "*system*" as "subject" that were not generated by me (I am the administrator). I don't know why these API keys are generated? What are the keys for and why there are so much?

Could you please explain to me and has anyone already had a problem?

Thank you for your help. Enclosed you will find a screenshot of the Access Token list from the Artifactory.

Thank you for your help .[Screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnMEI.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are access tokens used by the application to interact between different microservices internal to the jfrog application. [Access Tokens Overview](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Access+Tokens#AccessTokens-Overview) from JFrog Documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @vijay,but after reading your answer, does this mean that it is microservices like xray that create them to communicate for example artifactory communicates with xray or mission control?  the question that bothers me is how do these microservices generate them?  are they generated after installing these microservices on artifactory?

Comment: @SuzanneDalle The microservices are part of the JFrog Platform which includes Artifactory, Xray, Mission Control etc... More details on the microservices list & purpose can be found here in [the system arch page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/System+Architecture). These access tokens are created by Access microservice and is used by all products of the Jfrog Platform.

Comment: Okay ,now I am understanding very well ,the roles of this API Keys . But the First Token ou with subject„Admin“ is also created by access microservice right? Thank you very much for your explanation.

Comment: Yes it is. If the answer helped, please mark it as accepted. Welcome. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Thank You Suzzane.